# ClassNotFoundException when accessing Processing from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'm trying to run [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) from Eclipse but whenever I run the application as a Java Application I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Here's my full code:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class App extends PApplet {
    public void setup() {
        size(200,200);
        background(0);
    }

    public void draw() {
        stroke(255);
        if (mousePressed) {
            line(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX,pmouseY);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "App" });
    }


}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:6522)
    at com.WordClouds.App.main(App.java:17)
```

Comment: There is probably a library missing on your classpath.

Comment: @K.C. no because what this application in the main method does basically is to run App.class which is this class. So it just can't find this class!

Comment: Can you tell us how you compile and run it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably doing this tuturial : http://www.learningprocessing.com/tutorials/processing-in-eclipse/

You probably overlooked this :

> ```
> public static void main(String args[]) {
>    PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "MyProcessingSketch" });
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the String “MyProcessingSketch” must **match the name of your class (and if it is in a package, should include the package, i.e. packagename.MyProcessingSketch**).

Comment: If that solved the problem then "Here's my full code:" was incorrect. So for future reference: You omitted the `package` declaration?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with the class name correctly set and also the package. This solved my issue:

```
PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", MyProcessingSketch.class.getName() });
```